# How to print postgresql timestamp in python

Tags: python, postgresql

From my code in Python 3.5:

```
cur.execute("SELECT cdate FROM tru_" + uid + " WHERE signature='" + data[2:66] + "'")
results = cur.fetchall()
```

"cdate" it's a TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE on my PostgreSQL database, if I print "results" from my code in Python I get this:

```
[(datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 25, 11, 14, 36, tzinfo=psycopg2.tz.FixedOffsetTimezone(offset=0, name=None)),)]
```

I would like the print to produce a normal date and time format (e.g 2016-05-25 11:14:36), how can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are printing a list of tuples. Print just the timestamp:

```
print (results[0][0])
```

Answer (score 0):

this from clodoaldo print (results[0][0]) works but i think this is more descriptive (If I was reading code and saw [0][0] I would have no idea what it meant without spending an extra minute looking at the query):

```
for row in cur:
    print row["cdate"]
```

or

`row[0]['cdate']`

I would do this:

```
 [dt['cdate'].strftime("%Y-%m-%d") for dt, in results]

 ['2012-12-28','2012-12-28']
```

see datetime library  https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html